# Ubuntu 12.10 slowing down other devices on my network

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I'm very much a Linux noob, so this is probably something that's easy to fix or find out.

Ever since I installed Ubuntu, my internet speed seems to be good for my Ubuntu PC, but nothing else. Once I turn my PC off, or put it to sleep mood, the devices that were slow speed back up again.

This problem happens to my Nexus 7 and my PlayStation 3, so it's not a problem with an operating system, it's to do with the network and maybe Ubuntu in some way.

Any help would be appreciated, though I'm not that well known with Linux.

Comment: Have you checked in system monitor to see if Ubuntu is downloading anything?

Answer (score 3):

Two possible issues:

1. **Ubuntu is downloading stuff.** This could be background updates, something in Transmission (torrent), or a download in your browser.
2. **Your network card is slower.** Wireless networking is only as good as the least-capable node attached to it. This means if your PS3 and Nexus 7 are using 802.11n, and your computer uses 802.11g, then everything else is going to slow down to the 802.11g speeds and bandwidth (same goes for 802.11g vs 802.11b). Make sure your computer uses the same technology as at least one of the other two (the PS3 originally shipped with 802.11g, I don't know if they upgraded it; the Nexus should be 802.11n). If it's not, then upgrade it.

   - Alternatively, if your router supports dual-band output, you can split your wireless in to 5GHz and 2.4GHz. Put anything that supports it onto the 5GHz connection, and everything else on the 2.4GHz connection. That can help keep your slower nodes from slowing down the more capable one, though chances are the PS3 will still be stuck on the slower connection.